# Haskell module and data

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm new to Haskell. The following code shows a pair of integers. Let's say I want to sum up or subtract the pairs. How do I do that?

```
module IntPair where

data IntPair = IntPair Int Int
   deriving(Show)

plusIntPair :: IntPair -> Int
plusIntPair = undefined
```

Let's say I created an IntPair 1 2.
I should get answer 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use patterns to destructure your `IntPair`

Something like this should work (for the function):

```
plusIntPair :: IntPair -> Int
plusIntPair (IntPair a b) = a + b
```

In the snippet above, the first line declares that `plusIntPair` has type `IntPair -> Int`. The second line says that the function should destructure the data constructor `IntPair`, bind the first and second params to `a` and `b` respectively, and add them.

and to run it:

```
plusIntPair (IntPair 1 2)
```

`(IntPair 1 2)` constructs a value of type `IntPair`, `plusIntPair` is applied with the argument `IntPair 1 2`.

Comment: @user11984238 There are a few options. The simplest one is just to implement the function so it destructures both and adds them:

`addIntPair (IntPair a b) (IntPair c d) = IntPair (a + c) (b + d)`

Comment: Alright I got it before I saw this, but anyway thanks for the help.